# Output Location of Webpack Loaders

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm following along with the [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and [Webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) instructions.  I've gotten everything to work fine in development.  My question is about organization.

The [Angular 2 Webpack guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) says

> Although we tell Webpack to put output bundles in the dist folder, the
>   dev server keeps all bundles in memory; it doesn't write them to disk.
>   So we won't find any files in the dist folder (at least not any
>   generated from this development build).

And this is true- my `dist` folder is empty. However, after I run my npm start script, my `src`, `src/app`, and `config` folders have `.js` and `.js.map` files added to them for all their `.ts` files.

My question is, is it expected and is this a best practice? Should my compiled files be located in the same directory as the precompiled files?  Could I output them to separate folders to minimize the clutter in the folder with all my `.ts` files?

To avoid unnecessary bloat on this question, all my files are exactly as they are in the Webpack guide, before the section on Karma.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is expected and is this a best practice

It is common. You just gitignore these however e.g. I do this in alm : https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/ff7f0c5fa9f329dafdf2cfc61ffa0908c0c8f7f8/.gitignore#L5-L6